# Cannot convert value of type Appdata to expected argument type Object.type Realm Swift

Tags: swift, realm

How can I retrieve Realm Object data in my IOS App?

The Object class would be:

```js
import Foundation
import RealmSwift


class AppData: Object {

  dynamic var id = 0
  dynamic var tokeType = ""
  dynamic var token = ""
  dynamic var refreshToken = ""
  dynamic var accessToken = ""

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
  }

}
```

The next function I'm using to populate/update the AppData Realm Object:

```js
func register(_ instanceParameters : [String : AnyObject], completionHandler: @escaping ([Instance]?, NSError?) -> ()) {

    Alamofire.request(Router.register(instanceParameters)).responseJSON{ response in

      var instance = [Instance]()

      let AppDataObj = AppData()
      let config = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
          if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
          }
      })
      Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
      let realm = try! Realm()


      switch response.result {
      case .success(let json):
        let responseObject = json as? [String: AnyObject]
        instance.append(Instance(dictionary: responseObject!))

        AppDataObj.token = (instance.first?.token)!
        AppDataObj.tokeType = "Instance_Token"
        AppDataObj.id = 1

        try! realm.write {
          realm.add(AppDataObj, update: true)
        }   
        completionHandler(instance, nil)
      case .failure(let error):
        completionHandler(nil, error as NSError)
      }
    }
  }
```

and for the moment everything its OK and you can see below I can manage AppData Objects, using Realm Browser:

[image]

The problem I've found is when I need to use the Realm Object Data for Persistence trying to retrieve the AppData token:

```js
import RealmSwift

var AppDataObj = AppData()

let data = realm.object(ofType: AppDataObj, forPrimaryKey: "id")
loginParameters["token"] = AppDataObj.token as AnyObject? --> this line throws the error defined in the title of this question
```

Answer (score 0):

You should official guide first https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/.

First, you don't need to create Realm object's instance when you'd like to fetch persisted objects.

Second, you should pass an actual value to the `forPrimaryKey` perameter, not a property name. You saved the object as `id = 1`, so it should be `realm.object(ofType: AppDataObj, forPrimaryKey:`)`.

`object(ofType:forPrimaryKey:)` method returns a Realm object. So a correct code is:

```
import RealmSwift

let data = realm.object(ofType: AppDataObj, forPrimaryKey: 1)
loginParameters["token"] = data.token
```